# How to connect visual web developer (website) with SQL Server 2008 for website designing?

Tags: vb.net, string, sql-server-2008, connection

Am new for designing portal using visual web developer 2010 express edition. Almost i have finished designing work for a website. And, now i want to connect with database. but i dont know how to do  that. So can anyone help me on this. Specifications are below

1. Visual web developer 2010 express edition
2. SQL server 2008

Comment: Are Google **and** Bing both down at the same time!?!?!?!?

Comment: Here is a link that will help: [Working with data](https://www.google.com/#q=vb.net+working+with+database)